# How do I know if my microphone is mute or unmute when I have more than one microphone?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, audio, alsa, pulseaudio

How do I find out if my microphone is muted or unmuted, when I have more than one microphone such as Motherboard, USB and HDMI?

1) I can't find it with this:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards 
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xfe720000 irq 48
 1 [default        ]: USB-Audio - AK5370          
                      AKM              AK5370           at usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.1, full s
```

2) Nor with this

```
$ amixer -D 'hw:0' | grep Capture
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 46
  Front Left: Capture 22 [48%] [6.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 22 [48%] [6.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',1
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 46
  Front Left: Capture 42 [91%] [26.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 42 [91%] [26.00dB] [on]
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right

$ amixer -D 'hw:1' | grep Capture
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: Capture 0 - 78
  Mono: Capture 70 [90%] [12.00dB] [off]
```

3) Nor with:

```
$ pactl list | sed -n '/^Source/,/^$/p' | grep Mute
    Mute: yes
    Mute: no
    Mute: no

$ amixer scontrols
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
```

How can I get my `bash` (or other) script to read the value according to a `hw:value,value` format query?

Comment: Have you tried pressing F6 in alsamixer?

Answer (score 1):

you could try alsamixer, it resides in the alsa-utils package. it has a nice ncurses kind of gui.

Answer (score 0):

Your `amixer -D 'hw:1'` output actually shows the microphone state in the last line. Here's one way to extract that in a `bash` script:

```
amixer -D "hw:1" sget Mic | awk -F "[\[\]]" '/\[on|off\]/{ print $6 }'
```

Use `amixer`'s `-D` to specify a device, and `sget` to specify which `simple control` you want to query. For me, the simple control is `Mic`, but it might be different for you - use `amixer -D "hw:1"` to find out.

This works as long as `amixer` output doesn't change too much. What it does is:

1. pipe the output of `amixer` to `awk`,
2. filter out the lines not containing `[on]` or `[off]`. We thus end up with a single line `Mono: Capture 70 [90%] [12.00dB] [off]`
3. Extract and the print the 6th field from the line. The field separator is set to `[` or `]`, so this gets us the switch state string ("on" or "off").

Admittedly, not the most elegant solution, but I haven't found a way to force `amixer` to produce its output in a more structured way.